# Entity Framework Core Add Migration gives Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') in dotnet

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AuthConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=EmployeeLeaveDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True"
}
```

Here please check

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthConnectionString")));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>();
```

I was trying to add the migration but don't know why i am getting this error
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<$>b__0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\Seventhball\source\repos\EmployeeLeaveManagement\EmployeeLeaveManagement\Program.cs:line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If defined like this:**

```
"AuthConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=EmployeeLeaveDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True"
```

use this:

```
builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthConnectionString")
```

**if you define it like this:**

```
"ConnectionStrings": { "AuthConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=EmployeeLeaveDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"}
```

use this: :

```
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthConnectionString")
```